# System.Collections.Generic.List<T> size in memory

Tags: .net, memory-management

Just wondering if anyone has ever tried to determine the actual size of a System.Collections.Generic.List in memory?

I am currently caching one such object using System.HttpRuntime.Cache which seems to work well but I'd love to be able to determine the actual impact on my server.

```
using (System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(capacity)) 
{ 
        new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter().Serialize(stream, obj); 
        thisSerialized = stream.ToArray(); 
        return thisSerialized.Length; 
}
```

This works for others but not for what I need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The serialized size of the list will be totally irrelevant.

A `List<T>` will have a bit of overhead (two `int`s), and an array of size `Capacity`.

Arrays of reference types use `IntPtr.Size` (4 or 8) bytes of memory per element; arrays of value types use `Marshal.SizeOf(type)` bytes of memory per element.
(Arrays also have a bit of overhead)

Any reference types inside of the list (or in structs in the list) will use memory separately.

Comment: I've never tried to get the size using IntPtr, if you happen to have a code snippet I would love it.

Comment: @Hal: You can't. IntPtr.Size means 32 / 64 bit; it's the size of a single reference.